# apachelog shows http requests but not tcp connections

Tags: apache-2.2

I have installed the apachelog program on my ubuntu system. I have several virtual hosts that point to the same log file, so when I run the following, I should see all requests from the multiple sites:

```
$ apachetop -T 300 -f /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log
```

That should show all requests coming in starting now for the next 5 minutes. So I test it with multiple sites, and indeed it reports them:

```
last hit: 20:56:14         atop runtime:  0 days, 00:02:50             20:56:24
All:           10 reqs (   0.1/sec)       7443.0B (  103.4B/sec)     744.3B/req
2xx:       3 (30.0%) 3xx:       7 (70.0%) 4xx:     0 ( 0.0%) 5xx:     0 ( 0.0%)
R (170s):      10 reqs (   0.1/sec)       7443.0B (   43.8B/sec)     744.3B/req
2xx:       3 (30.0%) 3xx:       7 (70.0%) 4xx:     0 ( 0.0%) 5xx:     0 ( 0.0%)

 REQS REQ/S    KB KB/S URL
    3  0.04   6.0  0.1*/
    2  0.03   0.2  0.0 *
    1  0.01   0.2  0.0 /wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js
    1  0.01   0.2  0.0 /wp-content/themes/gd-theme/scripts/cycle.js
    1  0.01   0.2  0.0 /wp-content/themes/gd-theme/scripts/api.js
    1  0.01   0.2  0.0 /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
    1  0.06   0.2  0.0 /users/sign_in
```

One was from a wordpress site and another from ruby on rails site. Apache says there were 7 requests coming in. Maybe there were 7 http requests coming in (I highly doubt it because that ruby on rails site has several js and images to load), but actually there were only 2 tcp connections made and only two apache child processes should have been spawned, since I am using KeepAlive. Something definitely doesn't seem right with the output it is showing.

What may I be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apachetop` parses the access log of Apache.
Each requests gets individually written to this log regardless of whether it was requested in a single KeepAlive session or multiple TCP sessions.

`apachetop` cannot know anything about how many TCP connections have been made.
That access log also does not contain any information about Apache childs/threads, so it also cannot report those.

All it shows you is how many resources have been requested.

Comment: Well then this doesn't accomplish what I need. I need a program that tells me how many apache processes are active and how much private memory they are using collectively.

Comment: For that apachetop is not the proper tool. You might want to take a look at mod_status (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html).

Comment: the mod_status module with ExtendedStatus enabled does provide a lot of useful information. Unfortunately that doesn't give private memory usage either.

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers will open up multiple connections to load resources like javascript.  I see four of the requests are for java script.   These connection may be closed quickly.